# Why does this segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a factorial program that takes input from the terminal but it doesn't work..
giving it anything but no arguments gives a segmentation fault

```
// factorial calculator
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long factorial(long a) {
    if (a > 1)
        return (a * factorial(a-1));
    else
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long number = (long) argv[1];
    cout << number << "! = " << factorial(number) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

also for some reason number has the value of 140732199978159 when I do `./factorial 2`

(all I got from attempting to find an answer by searching was that a segfault means that I'm accessing something I'm not supposed to. I don't understand where I've done that here.)

Comment: You can't use a cast to turn a character string into the number it represents.

Comment: The program arguments are strings. Using a C-style case to make a "number" is not correct.

Comment: Use [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol): `long number = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);` -- you should also be testing that `argc` is _at least_ 2 before trying to access `argv[1]`.

Comment: Don't feel bad about this one. Casting in C++ is confusing sometimes. Sometimes it's used to do a bitwise transmute (`long` to `void*`, etc.), sometimes it does actual work to convert things (`int` to `double`, etc.), and sometimes it seems like it should do something but just doesn't (this question). Just make sure to carefully read the documentation before relying on a particular cast.

Comment: `(long)argv[1]` is not a valid way to turn interpret a string (e.g. "123") as a `long` - it causes undefined behaviour.   Assuming a 32-bit `long`,  factorial of `13` will overflow.   Assuming a 64-bit `long`, factorial of `21` will overflow.    Overflow of built-in signed integral types (like `long`) causes undefined behaviour.  In the case of recursive functions that can involve tromping the call stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long number = (long) argv[1];
```

This takes `argv[1]` and casts it to `long`. `argv` is a `char*[]` (for simplicity, I'll assume it's the very similar type `char**` for this explanation). Hence, `argv[1]` is a `char*`. Casting a `char*` to `long` takes its address as a numerical value. That's a position in memory on your computer and not helpful for calculating the factorial.

Consider [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), a built-in C++ function that does exactly what you want.

```
long number = std::strtol(argv[1], nullptr, 10);
```

`10` is the numerical base (we do our math in base 10, generally). The second argument is optional and not necessary for our use case, so we pass `nullptr` since we don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
(long) argv[1];
```

`argv[1]` is a `const char *`, a pointer to some unspecified number of characters.

Even if that character string happens to be `"2"`, converting the pointer to a `long` value, like this, does not get you an actual number 2. That's not how C++ works. All this does is reinterpret the raw memory address, that the pointer is pointing to. You get, pretty much, a junk number, and attempting to compute its factorial results in equally meaningless results.

You'll need to use some suitable library function, like `atol` from the C library, or `std::stol` from the C++ library (with some overhead due to a temporary conversion to a `std::string`) in order to get the expected results.